# Android firestore when users change the image, NullPointerException occurs

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making setup_profile activity. Users can change information.

When users do not change the image, it is good. But when the user change image errors come.

I add 'null checker' like
`if (uri!=null)` But I don know why it is.

Here are the errors.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
at com.razberrylovers.mbting.SetUpActivity.saveToFireStore(SetUpActivity.java:291)
at com.razberrylovers.mbting.SetUpActivity.access$700(SetUpActivity.java:40)
at com.razberrylovers.mbting.SetUpActivity$10.onComplete(SetUpActivity.java:217)

Here is my code.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_up);

    Toolbar setUpToolbar = findViewById(R.id.setup_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(setUpToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Profile");

    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    Uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
    mProfileName = findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
    mSaveBtn = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    mProfileSchool = findViewById(R.id.profile_school);
    mconcreteregion = findViewById(R.id.profile_concreteregion);


    // setting dialog
    textView_age=findViewById(R.id.age_dialog);

    textView_age.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new FragmentDialogBox().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
        }
    });

    textView_job=findViewById(R.id.job_dialog);
    textView_job.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Fragment_job().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
        }
    });

    textView_region = findViewById(R.id.region_dialog);
    textView_region.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Fragment_region().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
        }
    });

    textView_height = findViewById(R.id.height_dialog);
    textView_height.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Fragment_height().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
        }
    });

    textView_religion = findViewById(R.id.religion_dialog);
    textView_religion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Fragment_religion().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
        }
    });

    textView_drink = findViewById(R.id.drink_dialog);
    textView_drink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Fragment_drink().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
        }
    });

    textView_smoke = findViewById(R.id.smoke_dialog);
    textView_smoke.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Fragment_smoke().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
        }
    });

    textView_mbti = findViewById(R.id.mbti_dialog);
    textView_mbti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Fragment_mbti().show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"fragmentDialog");
        }
    });
```

and load data from firestore + mSaveBtn click listener(including the case of not changing the picture)

```
firestore.collection("Users").document(Uid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                if (task.getResult().exists()){
                    String name = task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String age = task.getResult().getString("age");
                    String job = task.getResult().getString("job");
                    String imageUrl = task.getResult().getString("image");
                    String school = task.getResult().getString("school");
                    String region = task.getResult().getString("region");
                    String concrete_region = task.getResult().getString("concrete_region");
                    String height = task.getResult().getString("height");
                    String religion = task.getResult().getString("religion");
                    String drink = task.getResult().getString("drink");
                    String smoke = task.getResult().getString("smoke");
                    String mbti = task.getResult().getString("mbti");
                    mProfileName.setText(name);
                    textView_age.setText(age);
                    textView_job.setText(job);
                    mProfileSchool.setText(school);
                    textView_region.setText(region);
                    mconcreteregion.setText(concrete_region);
                    textView_height.setText(height);
                    textView_religion.setText(religion);
                    mImageUri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
                    textView_drink.setText(drink);
                    textView_smoke.setText(smoke);
                    textView_mbti.setText(mbti);
                    Glide.with(SetUpActivity.this).load(imageUrl).into(circleImageView);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //

    mSaveBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String name = mProfileName.getText().toString();
        String age = textView_age.getText().toString();
        String job = textView_job.getText().toString();
        String school = mProfileSchool.getText().toString();
        String region = textView_region.getText().toString();
        String concrete_region = mconcreteregion.getText().toString();
        String height = textView_height.getText().toString();
        String religion = textView_religion.getText().toString();
        String drink = textView_drink.getText().toString();
        String smoke = textView_smoke.getText().toString();
        String mbti = textView_mbti.getText().toString();
        StorageReference imageRef = storageReference.child("Profile_pics").child(Uid+".jpg");
        //프로필 수정시 사진을 바꾸지 않았을 경우를 해결
        if(isPhotoSelected)
        {
            if (!name.isEmpty() && mImageUri != null) {

                imageRef.putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            saveToFireStore(task, name, age, job, school, region,
                                    concrete_region, height, religion, drink, smoke, mbti, imageRef);
                        } else {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, "등록을 하지 않은 것이 있습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

}
else{
saveToFireStore(null, name, age, job, school, region,
concrete_region, height, religion, drink, smoke, mbti, imageRef);
}
});
--> also code

Next code
There is a section that allows permission, and there is a saveToFireStore() method.-> when the task is null, the photo is not changed and when the task is not null photo will be changed.

```
circleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SetUpActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SetUpActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
                else{
                    CropImage.activity()
                            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                            .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                            .start(SetUpActivity.this);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void saveToFireStore(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task, String name,
                             String age, String job, String school, String region,
                             String concrete_region, String height, String religion,
                             String drink, String smoke, String mbti,
                             StorageReference imageRef) {
    if(task != null){

        imageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                downloadUri = uri;
            }

        });
    }
    else{

        downloadUri = mImageUri;

    }

    HashMap<String , Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", name);
    map.put("age", age);
    map.put("job", job);
    map.put("school", school);
    map.put("region", region);
    map.put("concrete_region", concrete_region);
    map.put("height", height);
    map.put("religion", religion);
    map.put("drink", drink);
    map.put("smoke", smoke);
    map.put("mbti", mbti);
    map.put("image",downloadUri.toString());

    firestore.collection("Users").document(Uid).set(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, "프로필이 등록되었습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(SetUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
            else{
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this,task.getException().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            mImageUri = result.getUri();
            circleImageView.setImageURI(mImageUri);
            isPhotoSelected = true;
        }
        else if(resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE){
            Toast.makeText(this,result.getError().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

The part of the error that logcat showed

```
imageRef.putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            saveToFireStore(task, name, age, job, school, region,
                                    concrete_region, height, religion, drink, smoke, mbti, imageRef);
                        } else {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and

```
@Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this, "프로필이 등록되었습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(SetUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
            else{
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(SetUpActivity.this,task.getException().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: No one has time to read that large code. Shorten the code only that you think causing issues!

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300 (three hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.